# Índices en array que no existen PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo un array en el que después de hacer unos borrados se me elimina uno de los índices, y después de ingresar nuevos campos, me rellena el siguiente índice obviando el que he eliminado, de manera que cuando recorro el array me da un error (Notice: Undefined offset: 5). El array se queda con un tamaño de 5, pero los índices siguen la secuencia 0 1 2 3 4 6, saltandose el 5.

¿De que manera se puede remover un índice que no está definido dentro de un array, o sea, como puedo hacer para que el índice 6 sea el índice 5?

He estado probando con array_splice pero no lo hayo. El array en cuestión es unique_array, pero no estoy seguro de si el fallo viene de antes, desde el tittle_array.

```html
<?php
    include('conexion.php');
    
    $query="SELECT titulo FROM LINKS";
    $result=mysqli_query($conection,$query);

    $title_array[]="";
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $title_array[$i] = $row[0];
        $i++;
    }

    $unique_array = array_unique($title_array);

    $id = 1;
    for ($j=0;$j<count($unique_array);$j++) {
        $consulta = $unique_array[$j];
        $query2="SELECT descripcion, enlace FROM LINKS WHERE titulo='$consulta'";
        $result2=mysqli_query($conection,$query2);

        echo "<h1 class='title'>$consulta</h1>";
        $des[]="";
        $enl[]="";
        $i=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
            $des[$i] = $row[0];
            $enl[$i] = $row[1];
            $i++;
        }
        echo "<div class='link'>";
        for($k=0;$k<count($des);$k++) {
            echo "<div class='link_item' id='link_item$id> data='$id'><a href='$enl[$k]' target='_blank'>$des[$k]</a><p class='delete' id='$des[$k]'>x</p></div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        array_splice($des,0);
        array_splice($enl,0);
        $id++;
    }
    mysqli_close($conection);
?>
```

Aquí elimino datos de la BBDD y se elimina del array

```html
<?php
    include('conexion.php');
    $enl = $_GET["id"];
    $query3="DELETE FROM LINKS WHERE descripcion='$enl'";
    $result3=mysqli_query($conection,$query3);
     if ($result3==false) {
        echo "Error eliminando registro.";
    } else {
        echo "Registro guardado.";
    }
    mysqli_close($conection);
?>
```

Y por si sirve de algo, paso las variable para eliminar el registro por js

```js
$del.on('click', function () {
    var boton = confirm("¿Eliminar enlace?");
    if (boton) {
        var service = $(this).attr('id');
        var dataString = "id=" + service;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "php/delete.php",
            data: dataString
        });
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Estas confundiendo los indices de la base de datos con los indices del array. el array se indexa segun las posiciones que tiene. La base de datos agrega indices segun va necesitando, y si borras uno no lo completa. Tu problema esta en suponer que al borrar un registro de la bd, se va a manejar de la misma manera que el array en memoria.

Comment: Pero entonces ¿por que desaparece el índice? He deducido que es al eliminar los datos de la bd. Al recorrer el array despues introduciendo otros campos me da error en el índice 5 y el 6 me lo muestra.

Comment: Como bien te dicen creo que estas confundiendo el indice del array con la clave primaria de la BD. Por otro lado hay bastantes cosillas que pulir en tu codigo, pero sobre todo no entiendo por que haces una consulta para traer los titulos y luego otra dentro de un bucle para el resto de campos de la misma tabla, en una sola consuta serviria. Si no te dan una respuesta certera intentare responderte por la mañana con todo lo que veo a mejorar.

Comment: Ok gracias. No llevo mucho tiempo con php, tengo que pulir mucho. Simplemente lo hice así por que he ido añadiendo código y lo he hecho por partes. El primero es solo para obtener los titulos, simplemente lo he separado para hacerlo más sencillo. Ni siquiera he puesto claves primarias en la tabla, pues estoy probando, de mysql domino bastante más que de php, por eso decía que el fallo se que está en que me desaparece el índice 5 del array. Al recorrerlo con un for me salta error en el índice 5 y me muestra el índice 6, teniendo un tamaño de 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analicemos un poco tu código primero

```
<?php
    include('conexion.php');

    $query="SELECT titulo FROM LINKS";
    $result=mysqli_query($conection,$query);

    // aquí no estas creando un Array vacío sino el primer elemento del array
    //$title_array[]="";
    $title_array = array();
    // no necesitas este contador
    //$i=0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        // aquí tampoco necesitas el contador 
        //$title_array[$i] = $row[0];
        $title_array[] = $row[0];
        // ni aqui
        //$i++;
    }
    // esto elimina los valores duplicados de un array
    $unique_array = array_unique($title_array);
     // Esta variable no tiene tampoco mucho sentido para utilizarla dentro de un for 
    $id = 1;
    // el count($unique_array) debería estar fuera del for, no queremos que se ejecute en cada ciclo del bucle
    for ($j=0;$j<count($unique_array);$j++) {
        // de verdad es necesario una segunda consulta a la misma tabla para el resto de campos?
         // consultas dentro de bucles y bucles anidados siempre son una mala idea 
        $consulta = $unique_array[$j];
        $query2="SELECT descripcion, enlace FROM LINKS WHERE titulo='$consulta'";
        $result2=mysqli_query($conection,$query2);

        echo "<h1 class='title'>$consulta</h1>";
        $des[]="";
        $enl[]="";
        $i=0;
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result2)) {
            $des[$i] = $row[0];
            $enl[$i] = $row[1];
            $i++;
        }
        echo "<div class='link'>";
        // otro bucle anidado prescindible
        for($k=0;$k<count($des);$k++) {
            echo "<div class='link_item' id='link_item$id> data='$id'><a href='$enl[$k]' target='_blank'>$des[$k]</a><p class='delete' id='$des[$k]'>x</p></div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
        // no se que pretendes con esto
        array_splice($des,0);
        array_splice($enl,0);
        $id++;
    }
    mysqli_close($conection);
```

Comentas que tu tabla no tiene una clave primaria (PK), he de decir que una tabla sin un PK no es más que un montón de datos basura, pues no hay forma de identificar inequívocamente un registro concreto entre otras.

No pretendo decirte que todo está mal, cuando comenzamos, también yo, hacemos burradas ineficientes, pero hay que intentar mejorar nuestro código día a día.

Tratare de darte un ejemplo lo más simple posible de como haría yo el código.

Supongamos la siguiente tabla en la base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE links
(
id_link INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
titulo VARCHAR(50),
descripcion VARCHAR(50),
enlace VARCHAR(50),
KEY(id_link)
)
```

Es recomendable para los nobles de las tablas y las columnas utilizar minúsculas.

Según deduzco de tu código, la finalidad es mostrar un listado de los enlaces, conteniendo cada ítem de la lista el título, el link  y la descripción. Vamos a ello:

```
<?php
// incluimos la conexión
include('conexion.php');
// Creamos la consulta 
$query = 'SELECT id_link, titulo, descripcion, enlace FROM links';
// ejecutamos la consulta y comprobamos la consulta 

if ( $result = mysqli_query($conection, $query) ) {
    // se ejecuto correctamente 
    // optener el número de filas devueltas en caso de que sea necesario
    $numero_filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // optener os y recorremos los resultados como un Array asociativo.
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) )
    {
        // armamos el contenido de la lista
        //el titulo
        echo "<h1 class='title'>".$row['titulo']."</h1>";
        // el enlace
        echo "<a href='".$row['enlace']."' target='_blank'>".$row['descrpcion']."</a>";
        // el párrafo para el delete ¿?, yo pondría un botón, con el id_link (PK) del registro
        echo "<p class='delete' id='".$row['id_link']."'>x</p>";
    }

    // Liberamos los resultados
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
else {
    echo 'Hubo algún problema con la consulta';
     //cerramos la conexion
     mysqli_close($conection);
    // finalizamos el script
    exit;
}

// cerramos la conexion
mysqli_close($conection);
```

Cómo ves el código queda mucho más limpio y reducido, aún quedaría añadir alguna que otra cosilla para dar formato html, pero eso es cosa tuya.

Comment: Muchas gracias Xerif, ahora mismo me pongo a ello y mejorar el código con toda la información que me has dado. La verdad es que es mi primer programa completo que hago en php, antes solo habia trasteado, y tengo todo mezclado y muy poco eficiente. El problema que tenía no hubiera sido ni un problema si hubiera programado como tu me has indicado. Al final resolví el problema, ahora postearé la solución que encontré para lo de array. Saludos

Comment: Si crees que la respuesta es la que más se acerca a una solución marcala como aceptada. Por otro lado si hubieses puesto un ejemplo claro de lo que querías con el Array, creo que rápidamente alguien te hubiese indicado que las claves no se reenumeran solas. Igualmente espero te haya servido de ayuda mi respuesta. Un saludo @asantana o

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda, que una vez eliminado el registro debes de volver a actualizar y cargar tu Array con los nuevos datos, debes de asegurarte que no utilice datos de memoria, sino que descargue nuevamente y refresque la vista.

Comment: ¿Y como debo hacerlo? ¿En el delete.php? Había pensado separar el primer archivo, que es el que está primero y poner por un lado la consulta y el array guardado y por otro el resto, así en el delete incluir ese nuevo archivo y manejar el array. ¿Va por ahi? Mañana lo probaré. Gracias por la respuesta

Comment: Aunque la respuesta esta bien, deberias agregar toda la informacion para que OP entienda la solucion. No es necesario todo el codigo, pero si por lo menos ayudar con unas lineas y explicando los pasos necesarios.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la solución que encontré a los índices eliminados.

```html
<?php
    $array = ['1','2','3','4'];

    foreach ($array as $valor) {
        echo $valor."\n";
    }
    //Salida --> 1 2 3 4

    unset($array[2]);

    foreach ($array as $valor) {
        echo $valor."\n";
    }
    //Salida --> 1 2 4
    
    echo $array[2];
    //Salida --> Notice: Undefined offset: 2

    echo $array[3];
    //Salida --> 4
?>
```

Al hacer unset el elemento desaparece, y con él, el índice también. Para resolver este problema mi solución fue crear un nuevo array, al que le aplico la función array_values, que devuelve los elementos del array colocandolos en el mismo orden. Así el nuevo array tiene todos los índices sin saltar ninguno.

```html
<?php 
    $array2 = array_values($array);    
    echo $array2[2];
    //Salida --> 4
?>
```